# Heroku Hosted Website - Non working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, heroku

I have a site hosted on Heroku (https://steadysolescheckoutsim.herokuapp.com/) and when the site is loaded the timer is supposed to automatically start and when you click the Purchase button a fake Stripe checkout should pop up. This has all worked on local host, but not on Heroku.

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Steady Soles</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Checkout sim || open source">
        <meta name="author" content="@jxcvby">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <script src="./files/jquery-3.3.1.js.download"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="./files/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./files/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./files/animate.css">
        <script src="./files/wow.min.js.download"></script>
        <link href="./files/css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="./files/v3"></script>
        <script>
            new WOW().init();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
        <div id="loader-wrapper" class="wrapper-loader" style="display: none;">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div id="loader">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mainpage" id="mainpage">
            <nav class="nav-bar">
                <div class="logo-nav">
                    <img src="./files/logo.png" class="logo-nav-image">
                </div>
                <div class="right-nav">
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;;">Features</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;">Retailers</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;">App</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;">Success</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;">FAQ</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><span style="color:#fff;">Help</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-nav">
                        <p align="center"><button class="dashboard">Dashboard</button></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <br>
            <h1 style="color:#fff;">00:00:00</h1>
            <button id="start" class="dashboard">start</button>
            <button id="clear" class="dashboard">clear</button>
            <div id="pop_checkout" class="login-container hide">
                <p align="center" class="title-checkout">
                    <img src="./files/logo.png" class="logo-checkout">
                </p>
                <p align="center">
                    <input type="text" class="email" placeholder="Email">
                </p>
                <div class="stripe-elements">
                    <div id="CardNumberHolder" class="cardnumber StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame5" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="./files/elements-inner-card-454fa437f26b2584d8ab85e3bac96af2.html" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; user-select: none !important; height: 14.4px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="CardExpireHolder" class="cardexpiry StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame6" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="./files/elements-inner-card-454fa437f26b2584d8ab85e3bac96af2(1).html" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; user-select: none !important; height: 14.4px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="CardCvvHolder" class="ccv StripeElement StripeElement--empty">
                        <div class="__PrivateStripeElement" style="margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; border: none !important; display: block !important; background: transparent !important; position: relative !important; opacity: 1 !important;"><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeFrame7" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="./files/elements-inner-card-454fa437f26b2584d8ab85e3bac96af2(2).html" title="Secure payment input frame" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; user-select: none !important; height: 14.4px;"></iframe><input class="__PrivateStripeElement-input" aria-hidden="true" aria-label=" " autocomplete="false" maxlength="1" style="border: none !important; display: block !important; position: absolute !important; height: 1px !important; top: 0px !important; left: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; margin: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; opacity: 0 !important; background: transparent !important; pointer-events: none !important; font-size: 16px !important;"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p></p>
                <p align="center" class="button">
                    <button class="login" id="stop">
                    Purchase
                    </button>
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="container" id="closepop">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <p align="center" class="title"><span class="whitelarge"><b>Steady Soles Restock Simulator</b></span></p>
                    <p align="center" class="grey"><span class="medium">Need to better your skills in catching restocks?<br>Best place to do it, for our members only.</span></p>
                    <p align="center"><button class="dashboard" id="PurchaseBtn">Purchase</button></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var myVar;

            function myFunction() {
              myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 800);
            }

            function showPage() {
              document.getElementById("loader-wrapper").style.display = "none";
              var element = document.getElementById("mainpage");
              element.classList.remove("hide");
            }
        </script>
        <script src="./files/index.js.download"></script><iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeController1" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="./files/controller-89bb338e439a55d87e8fb37a06ff881e.html" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; visibility: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; height: 1px !important; pointer-events: none !important; user-select: none !important;"></iframe>
        <script src="./files/jquery.min.js.download"></script>
        <script src="./files/bootstrap.min.js.download"></script>
        <iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="__privateStripeMetricsController0" allowpaymentrequest="true" src="./files/outer.html" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="border: none !important; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 1px !important; min-width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden !important; display: block !important; visibility: hidden !important; position: fixed !important; height: 1px !important; pointer-events: none !important; user-select: none !important;"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am running it as a PHP app as well and I included an index.php file that looks like such:

```
<?php include_once("index.html"); ?>
```

Please let me know if you need to see other files such as css, etc.

Comment: Try resolving errors that are coming up in console.

Comment: I looked at the console and there were no significant errors, I did however have a 404 for wow.min.js.download not sure if that's the issue

Comment: if any code tries to call wow.js then your js will probably stop working. try and resolve your 404

Comment: I commented out all sections that were given 404s and it still works on local host, but not on heroku i'm pushing each change properly. really stuck here. I'm pretty new to using heroku so i might be missing something.